# Upgrade Azure SQL server

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have created a Single Database instance which is running on SQL server versioned 12.0.2000.8(2014) and would like to upgrade this to a latest version. Can someone help me with detailed steps. Thanks in advance.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Azure SQL DB is a managed service so it will be automatically updated by Microsoft. I haven't seen any selection for different versions or updates anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure always have the latest upgraded version, so there's no action needed from your end, that's why its easy in PaaS.

You can check more info [here](https://dataedo.com/kb/query/azure-sql/check-server-version) to know which is the current version available

Comment: Hi @Rakesh : If my response helped you, can you please mark it as an answer so that we can have others from community to benefit from it :). Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Azure SQL Database is SQL Server database engine, based on the latest stable Enterprise Edition of SQL Server. We can not updates anywhere.

[image]

As seen in the diagram, each service offering can be characterized by the level of administration you have over the infrastructure, and by the degree of cost efficiency.

Comment: Hi @Rakesh Adoni, If my answer is helpful for you, please accept(mark) it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members.  : )